# Collect distances (and restore path) from 1 point to all others in a graph

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, math, graph

**Problem:**
I have a weighted graph. I want to get distance from definite point to all other points in the graph.(and then get path to them) 
I used modified [dijkstra algorithm](https://wiki2.org/en/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

So, here is code:

```
var get_path = function(graph, a) {
// declaration
let cache, i, v, queue, node, links, root,
    j, link, c, n, d, max, w, L = graph.length;

// initialization
cache = Array(L);
i = L;
while (--i >= 0) {
    v = graph[i];
    cache[v.id] = {
        id: v.id,
        distance: Infinity,
        links: v.links,
        prev: null,
    };
}
root = cache[a];
root.distance = 0;
queue = [root];

// processing
i = 0;
while (i < queue.length) {
    node = queue[i];
    links = node.links;
    j = links.length;
    while (--j >= 0) {
        link = links[j];
        c = cache[link.id];
        d = node.distance + link.weight;
        if (d < c.distance) {
            c.prev = node;
            c.distance = d;
            queue.push(c);
        }
    }
    i++;
}




return cache;
```

}

**Graph format** is:

```
graph = [
  {
    id: 1,
    links: [
      {
        id: 2,
        weight: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        weight: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    links: [
      {
        id: 1,
        weight: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        weight: 2,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    links: [
      {
        id: 1,
        weight: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        weight: 3,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    links: [
      {
        id: 2,
        weight: 2,
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        weight: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        weight: 3,
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        weight: 1,
      }
    ]
  }, 
  {
    id: 5,
    links: [
      {
        id: 4,
        weight: 1,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Performance:**
In my PC this algorithm works with graph of ~160 vertices and ~350 edges about 0.03-0.06ms. But I need faster!

You can measure performance on your PC [here](https://jsfiddle.net/magneto903/1t05qnwj/)

**Question:**
How to make this code (function `get_path()`) faster? Is it possible on JavaScript? If I should change the format of graph to make algorithm faster it's not a problem.

Or I exhausted possibilities of JavaScript?

Comment: If you need faster, do you mean you have  graphs that are a lot larger, or that you have many graphs to solve?

Comment: As your question states you want the distances, you can already drop the management of `prev`.

Comment: if you need to calculate all shortest path, consider using Floyd-Warshall algorithm

Comment: also, cosndier using networkx. It has these algorithms ready for you

Comment: @trincot, I have graph, that change every frame. I need to run this algorithm from different point of this graph in one frame. Also I need possibily to restore the path, so ```prev``` helps me to do it.

Comment: @Christian Sloper, no, I dont need to get distance/path from every point to every point. I need to get distance/path from fixed point to every point. So, Floyd-Warshall will work longer than Dijkstra. Do you know, is networkx's algorithms fast?

Comment: Questions about performance are better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Before we look into optimization, I need to question the correctness of your implementation. Dijkstra's algorithm needs to run until the frontier set (represented by `queue` in your implementation) is empty. You are using a counter `i` in your implementation, I don't see how this will give correct results. Have you tried your implementation with other larger graphs to check the correctness?

Comment: @wookie919, That works correct. But this is modified Dijkstra. I tried this on bigger graphs (more than 100 vertices and 300+ edges) and got correct results.